# MonoGame in GTK#

Tags: c#, monogame, mono

I was wondering if it's possible to embed a MonoGame instance not in the standard window, but rather in a GTK# widget. If yes, how could I do it? Do I have to write a custom widget? Is it even better to switch to OpenTK even though it seems quite counter-productive to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible, but a little trickier than vanilla winforms MonoGame.
There's a good tutorial here : http://www.oldschoolpixels.com/?p=390

Switching to OpenTK is not advisable. MonoGame has *a lot* of things that aren't in OpenTK when it comes to texture loading, entity management, etc.

Think of OpenTK as a relatively barebones way to talk to OPENGL from .NET